# How to see POST parameters in Network tab for POST request that returns a 303 Redirect

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, post

I have a form which when submitted, performs a persist operation and then returns a 303 redirect to a different url.

When I see the request in browser's Network tab, I cannot see the post parameters of the request. In the response, it shows the 303 redirect things which are fine. But POST parameters cannot be seen anywhere. How can I see the values sent as part of the post request.

Comment: I also noticed this today. Me and my co-worker have Chrome 61 and form values ***are not*** show in the `Headers` tab in *Developer Tools* for POST requests which end up with 303. Other co-worker with Chrome 60 sees the values. This looks like a bug in Chrome 61 to me.

Comment: @Smuuf Yes it does seem like a bug. Anyway to get around that, you may just install any browser extension that intercepts each request. It shows all the parameters. One of such extensions is HTTP Trace.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug in chrome version. You can use a browser extension, one being HTTP Trace that shows all the info.